# Checking if all objects of an array is active at the same time Unity C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've tried to make a script that if all the lights in my scene tagged "Light" are active at the same time, the game proceeds. None of the answers I've found have helped so far. I always end up with it only scanning the active objects, just randomly jumping out of the loop, or stopping when it has found one object that's active. Here is a simple piece of code that should have worked according to other posts

```
    void Update()
    {
        bool allActive = false;
        GameObject[] allLights = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Light");
        if(currenObjective > 0 && currenObjective < 3)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allLights.Length; i++)
            {
                if (allLights[i].activeInHierarchy)
                {
                    allActive = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (allActive)
            {
                currentObjective = 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code just sets the allActive variable to true at the moment *one* light is turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to invert the check:

```
private void Update()
{
    // Since Find is always a bit expensive I would do the cheapest check first
    if(currenObjective > 0 && currenObjective < 3)
    {
        var allLights = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Light");
        var allActive = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < allLights.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!allLights[i].activeInHierarchy)
            {
                allActive = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (allActive)
        {
            currentObjective = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or You can do this in one line using [Linq `All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all)

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void Update()
{
    // Since Find is always a bit expensive I would do the cheapest check first
    if(currenObjective > 0 && currenObjective < 3)
    {
        var allLights = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Light");

        if (allLights.All(light => light.activeInHierarchy))
        {
            currentObjective = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

---

As a general note: You should avoid using `FindGameObjectsWithTag` every frame! Either store these references **ONCE** at start, or if you spawn more lights on runtime implement it event driven and add the newly spawned lights to a list and then use that list to check.

Answer (score 3):

If i understant you want to know if all objects are active:
    using Linq does the job

you have to add using system.Linq to your script.

```
    GameObject[] allLights = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Light");
    bool result = allLights.All(p => p.activeInHierarchy);
```

you could simplify your code like this:

```
private void Update()
{
    if(currenObjective > 0 && currenObjective < 3 && GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Light").All(p => p.activeInHierarchy))
    {
        currentObjective = 2;
    }
}
```

As says derHugo, FindGameObjectsWithTag is very expensive in each frame...